# Multiple subscriptions to Observable sequence Rx c#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I am trying to learn Rx framework in .NET and in the process of applying it one of the tasks that I am working on. The functionality that I am trying is explained in this simple use case below.

I have a sequence of IEnumerable which I need to process in parallel and apply a function( async function ) to it which returns an int. based on the value returned. In the code below the new sequences oddSequence and evenSequence are created only after the original "sequence" is created, so there is not real "fire and forget" happening here. What is correct way to approach this problem using Rx?

```
    public void TestRx()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> inputs = new string[] { "T-1", "T-2", "T-3"};

        var sequence = inputs.ToObservable().Select(x => ReturnResult(x)).Merge();

        var oddSequence = sequence.Where(x => (x%2) != 0);
        var evenSequence = sequence.Where(x => (x%2) == 0);

        oddSequence.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine($"ODD VALUE {i}"));
        evenSequence.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine($"EVEN VALUE {i}"));
    }

    public async Task<int> ReturnResult(string s)
    {
        int result = -1;
        Int32.TryParse(s.Split('-')[1], out result);
        return result;
    }
```

Thank you helping me out

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have an observable sequence X<T> which is processed in parallel and I want to take specific action based on the value T computed. Action taken depends on the value of T computed.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
private Random random = new Random();

public void TextRx()
{
    new[] {"T-1", "T-2", "T-3"}
        .Select(s => ReturnResult(s).ToObservable())
        .Merge()
        .GroupBy(i => i % 2 == 0)
        .SelectMany(g => g.Select(i => (g.Key, Value: i)))
        .Subscribe(o => Console.WriteLine($"{(o.Key ? "EVEN" : "ODD")} VALUE {o.Value}"));
}

public async Task<int> ReturnResult(string s)
{
    await Task.Delay(random.Next(5000));
    int.TryParse(s.Split('-')[1], out var result);
    return result;
}
```

- It uses `ValueTuple`, which is a C# 7 feature. You'd need to grab it with Nuget. Of course you could use an anonymous object, but I prefer `ValueTuple`. It's also using `out` variables from C#7 and string interpolation from C# 6.

Comment: This answers the specific OP's question, but doesn't answer the question in the title "Multiple subscriptions to observable sequence".